# POST when clicking button

Tags: php, ajax, forms, bootstrap-modal

So, I am trying to POST a variable to my controller when pressing a button (it will be created a button for each variable in a `foreach` loop).

When pressing this button, I want to POST this variable, so I can request it in my controller. When pressing this button, I also want my Modal to activate in the UI.

button (I use it now as a submit button).

```
<form action="" method="post">
       <button name="editUser" value="<?php echo $userResults['userID']; ?>"></button>
</form>
```

Later down in my view page, I also want to use the variable that was posted.

```
foreach ($userResults1 as $userResults1):
    if (isset($_POST['editUser'])) {

        $givenUserID = $_REQUEST["editUser"];

        if ($userResults1['userID'] == $givenUserID) {
            ?>
            <form action="?page=editUserEngine" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="editUserID" value="<?php echo $userResults1['userID']; ?>"><br>
                Navn: <br>
                <input type="text" name="editName" value="<?php echo $userResults1['name']; ?>"><br>
                Brukernavn: <br>
                <input type="text" name="editUsername" value="<?php echo $userResults1['username']; ?>"><br>
                Passord: <br>
                <input type="text" name="editPassword" value="<?php echo $userResults1['password']; ?>"><br>
                Brukernivå: <br>
                <input type="text" name="editUserLevel" value="<?php echo $userResults1['userLevel']; ?>"><br>
                Epost: <br>
                <input type="text" name="editEmail" value="<?php echo $userResults1['email']; ?>"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Lagre">
            </form>

            <?php
        }
    }
endforeach;
```

In my Controller, i REQUEST the variables and pass it on to my Model:

```
private function userEditEngine() {
    $editUserID = $_REQUEST["editUserID"];
    $editName = $_REQUEST["editName"];
    $editUsername = $_REQUEST["editUsername"];
    $editPassword = $_REQUEST["editPassword"];
    $editUserLevel = $_REQUEST["editUserLevel"];
    $editEmail = $_REQUEST["editEmail"];

    $userEditInfo = $GLOBALS["userModel"];
    $edited = $userEditInfo->editUser($editUserID, $editName, $editUsername, $editPassword, $editUserLevel, $editEmail);

    header("Location:index.php?page=createUser");
}
```

This does work fine, but now I want to add a Modal, and display my form inn the Modal, but since I have to refresh the page to pass my variable with submit button, I kill the variable and my modal cant find it...

```
<td class="text-center">
<form id="brukerRedForm" action="" method="post">
</form>
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#brukerModal" type="submit">
    <button form="brukerRedForm" type="button" name="editUsers" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Rediger bruker" value="<?php echo $userResults['userID']; ?>" 
            style="appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            outline: none;
            border: 0;
            background: transparent;
            display: inline;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="color: green"></span></button>
</span>
```

I probably have to use Ajax, but I don't get it to work. Anyone that have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can store the value of your variable in a session variable. For example:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['editUser'] = $_POST['editUser'];
```

Comment: Did think about ut, but I found a workaround with activating the Modal IF editUser is posted, insted of activating the modal on posting. This is working fine, but I really wanted to POST on buttonclick using ajax, but I couldn't make it work